# dd , pv , gzip and exclude directory, possible?

Tags: linux, compression, dd, gzip, exclude

Is it possible to do the following:

```
dd if=/dev/hdx | pv | gzip > /path/to/image.img\
--exclude=/temp --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/proc --exclude=/path/to/image.img
```

So I want to make a backup to an image that is compressed with gzip, but I want to exclude some directories and the file to where it is being written, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `dd` if you want to exclude some directories and/or files, it's nigh-impossible (without corrupting the filesystem by deleting sectors seemingly at random).

And you can't make a proper `dd` backup of a mounted partition either, for the same reasons you can't `fsck` a mounted partition (since it sounds like you're asking *"I want to `dd if=sda of=sda"*)

And you could do this with `dd` instead of using `pv`:

> Sending  a USR1 signal to a running 'dd' process makes it print I/O sta‐
>          tistics to standard error and then resume copying.
>
> ```
> $ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null& pid=$!
> $ kill -USR1 $pid; sleep 1; kill $pid
> ```
>
> 18335302+0 records in 18335302+0  records  out  9387674624  bytes
>       (9.4 GB) copied, 34.6279 seconds, 271 MB/s

But, you'd probably be better off using `tar` with possibly some options like:

```
 --exclude=PATTERN
       exclude files, given as a PATTERN

 --exclude-tag=FILE
       exclude contents of directories containing FILE, except

 --exclude-tag-all=FILE
       exclude directories containing FILE

 --exclude-tag-under=FILE
       exclude everything under directories containing FILE

 -z, --gzip, --gunzip --ungzip

 -J, --xz

 -T, --files-from FILE
       get names to extract or create from FILE

 -X, --exclude-from FILE
       exclude patterns listed in FILE
```

See `man tar` and countless examples on the web.

Unless you're backing up some strange OS or programs that expect files to be in a certain spot on the disk, then you might want a `dd` copy of a whole *unmounted* partition/disk, piped to `gzip`/`xz`/etc.